# Trying to write a function in SML

Tags: logic, sml

I am trying to write a function in sml that takes a list as its first argument and a number as its second.  The result should be:  greaterT [3,5,2,4,7]3;  val it = [5,4,7] : int list

This is my work so far but doesn't work yet.

```
fun greaterT ([],k) = []
|   greaterT (a::x,k)
if a <= k
then x = [] 
else greaterT(x,k);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _doesn't work_?

Comment: Getting errors when running it in SML of new jersey,Errors types of if branches do not agree   then branch: bool  else branch: Z list in expression  if a <= k
then x = [] 
else greaterT(x,k);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting into problems because the `then` branch of the `if` expression is trying to do something which doesn't make sense:

```
x = []
```

You can't re-assign values to already bound identifiers in Standard ML, although you can achieve mutability using [`ref`s](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/recitations/rec15.html), but they're not needed in this case.

In your case, what the required function conceptually does, is to look at the first element of a list, decide whether to keep it in the final result by comparing it with `k` and then recurse on the rest of list:

```
fun greaterT ([], k) = []
  | greaterT (a :: rest, k) =
      if a <= k then
        a :: greaterT (rest, k)
      else
        greaterT (rest, k)
```

The above isn't a good solution, though, because the first recursive call isn't in a tail position, so the compiler can't optimize the generated code (for reasons I won't discuss here; there are plenty of [questions about tail-call optimizations on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tail-call+optimizations)).

So, a better version would use an extra parameter in which it accumulates elements that satisfy the `<=` predicate.

```
fun greaterTailRec ([], k, result) = List.rev result
  | greaterTailRec (a :: rest, k) =
      if a <= k then
        greaterTailRec (rest, k, result)
      else
        greaterTailRec (rest, k, a :: result)

fun greaterT (list, k) = greaterTailRec (list, k, [])
```

We can go a step further and generalize `greaterTailRec` by replacing the specifics, which in this particular case is the comparison call `<=`, to a more general call to a function that takes an element of the list as argument and returns a `bool`. Thus, we'll end up with a generally useful function called `filter`:

```
fun filter predicate list =
  let
    fun recur ([], result) = List.rev result
      | recur (a :: rest, result) =
          if predicate a then
            recur (rest, a :: result)
          else
            recur (rest, result)
  in
    recur (list, [])
  end

fun greaterT (list, k) =
  filter (fn a => a >= k) list
```

The [`filter` helper function](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.filter:VAL) is already defined on the [`List` structure](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html), so your initial function can be more concisely expressed as:

```
fun greaterT (list, k) =
  List.filter (fn a => a >= k) list
```